# I want to boot Ubuntu from a old PC internal HDD with USB adapter

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, windows-8

i have an HDD with Ubuntu from my old, broke notebook, i have a HDD2USB adapter and i need to boot it from this external HDD.

If i take of the Win8 HDD and place the ubuntu's one, all work's fine, but Ubuntu and Win8 don't boot from external HDD.

What i do wrong!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your able to boot up the Ubuntu on your notebook, or any other computer.
[try to do this](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/)

There are several ways you can do it.

**if you only have access to one computer that's working then do this:**

1. Boot up your Ubuntu installation.
2. Install vmware workstation.
3. load up vmware workstation and go to file -> visualize an physical machine.
4. when you have visualize your physical installation of ubuntu: 
   right click on it in vmware workstation, go to settings and under general you will se the machines "working Directory" Copy the content of that folder, to an external hdd or usb stick.
5. Install an fresh installation of ubuntu, following [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) (remember to install the same version of Ubuntu, as the one you had on your notebook.
6. when you have done this, boot up your new ubuntu installation, install vmware workstation again, and import the virtual machine you have located on your USB/External HDD. and make sure its accessible on the local network.
7. and then [try this](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/)

**if you have access to an other computer, that you can boot up the old ubuntu installation on, then boot it up, make sure its accessable on the local network and [try this](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/) **

if your stucked, try to google any of the steps. there are plenty of guides on how to do the different steps.